# How to get GTK2 working on Windows with CLion?

Tags: windows, gtk, clion, msys

> **I installed GTK2 on my Windows machine via MSYS using the command**

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gtk2
```

> After installing the package, I added the following lines to my
>   CMakeLists.txt:

```
include(FindGTK2)
if (GTK2_FOUND)
    include_directories(${GTK2_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    link_directories(${GTK2_LIBRARY_DIRS})
    link_libraries(${GTK2_LIBRARIES})
endif (GTK2_FOUND)
```

I started a HelloWorld program which uses `#include <gtk/gtk.h>`, but get an error stating `Cannot find 'gtk'`

**I am running CLion 2017.3.1 with CMake 3.9. The CMakeCache.txt shows that GTK2 directories are not found. How can I redirect this so that it points to GTK2?**

Comment: Why do you use `include` ? Shouldn't you call `find_package` instead?